# Sql request into 2 tables to get percentage of each rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 SQL tables like this:

**___Rooms:**

```
ROO_Id    ROO_Number
1         101
2         201
```

**___Bookings:**

```
BOO_Id    BOO_RoomNumber
1         1   
2         1
3         2
```

I want to echo a table with all rooms I have with percentage for each.

```
BOO_RoomNumber percentage count
101            66%         2 
201            33%         1
```

Thanks.

Comment: You need to be more specific regarding what you've done and where you're hung up. How do you pull the bookings for a given room? With an `INNER JOIN` over `bookings.roomId` and `rooms.id`? Or some other way? Do you want a way to get this straight out of an sql query, or is it fine to do this in the application layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer:

**UPDATED**

```
select r.ROO_Number BOO_RoomNumber, ((ifnull(cnt_book,0)*100)/(select count(*) from Bookings)) percentage, ifnull(cnt_book,0) `count`
from Rooms r left join (select BOO_RoomNumber, count(*) cnt_book
           from Bookings
           group by BOO_RoomNumber) cnt on r.ROO_Id=cnt.BOO_RoomNumber
```

Working [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16ad5/2)

Comment: Thanks, I have update my question to avoid misunderstanding. Could you please update your answer as well. It ll be the good one.

Comment: Hi, @user3504260. What should i update in my answer? Isn't it same as you want? (except `%` sign and round decimal percentage up to two decimal places)

Comment: That field name modification you can do I guess. Need not to re-create Fiddle.

Comment: Hi Log1c. Yes but not at 100% as tables were misunderstanding. Is that possible to update your code please? Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
SELECT r.id as BOO_RoomNumber, ((booked/(select count(id) from BOOKINGS))*100) as percentage, booked as `count`
FROM ROOMS as r
LEFT JOIN 
(
SELECT count(id) as booked, roomId
FROM BOOKINGS
GROUP BY roomId
) as b on b.roomId=r.id
```

Comment: It won't output average,Asker wants **average**. It will just output count total bookings of each rooms